# Issues in working of PHP form submit with GET data

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working with PHP forms. 
The opening form tag looks like this:

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="<?php echo $targetpage; ?>" method="GET">
```

This generated the following HTML:

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="index.php?&amp;rel=common_listing&amp;module=company&amp;sort_option=&amp;search_option=&amp;show_max_row=15" method="GET">
```

When I submit this form, I land on a URL:

```
http://localhost/projectcode12may2014/ampanel/index.php?field%5B%5D=broker_name&adv_operation%5B%5D=LIKE&value%5B%5D=&query_type%5B%5D=AND&submit=Submit
```

But what I want is that

`?field%5B%5D=broker_name&adv_operation%5B%5D=LIKE&value%5B%5D=&query_type%5B%5D=AND&submit=Submit`

should be appended to the action URL on the landing page. Can anyone suggest any good method for doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `method="get"` the parameters in action are overwritten. Only what is in the from will be transmitted.

You need to add hidden fields for all these values. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="module" value="company" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is your from data.

You have `method="get"` in your form tag. This means that the form data is concatinated to the URL. Use `method="post"` to have send form data as a POST request and keep your URI clean.

So change this line

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="<?php echo $targetpage; ?>" method="GET">
```

to this

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="<?php echo $targetpage; ?>" method="post">
```

Then you can access your form data in PHP with the global `$_POST` var which holds an array with the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior. Using GET method discard all parameters specified directly in action attribute.

Use POST method instead or move parameters from action attribute of the form to input fields with type="hidden".